# LaTeX for the Lao language

Tags: languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tajik language in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12666/tajik-language-in-latex)

With a friend, I would like to develop LaTeX in Lao (a language that is close to Thai). There is already a thaitex Babel set so I guess it should not be that difficult. But I am a total novice in developing languages for LaTeX, so I don't even know at which kind of files I should look. Can someone give me some clues?

Comment: Although I agree that this is effectively a duplicate, the relevance of a question about Tajik to a question about Thai is not immediately apparent, and furthermore, differences between the Cyrillic and Thai scripts may make some of the relevant problems different.  It would therefore make sense to make a community wiki page that addresses the question of adding new languages generally.

Comment: I suggest reopening this question. Although the basic answer on the linked duplicate provides some good general information, there are many issues regarding word wrapping and hyphenation in Lao that are exceeding complex. (Whether opening will result in some actual answers is another issue.)

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I agree (and fear) that lao language may raise issues that tajik language does not (and vice & versa) but at least I now have a guide line.

Comment: I totally agree the idea of a wiki page that addresses the question of adding new languages generally. When it will be done, I promise to make a report of the encountered pbms (and, hopefully, how I fixed them).

Comment: the CW question about languages is [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14095/215)

Answer (score 3):

I'd comment (or at least CW) if I could, but:

[Polyglossia](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/xetex/latex/polyglossia/), a XeLaTeX package, supports Lao, and may serve as a reference framework for your own efforts. Admittedly, I have not worked extensively with Xe, so I don't know if the methods used there would be incompatible with LaTeX methods.

Good luck!

Comment: Good start! I made it CW as requested, so everybody can contribute by editing and adding further tips.