# Support for languages other than English in LaTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, unicode, languages, big-list

I am currently using fully updated TeX Live 2022 and I am very happy to see a lot of new advancements in LaTeX which make typesetting languages other than English easy and more convenient. I have seen (and actively participated in) the development of support for Marathi language in LaTeX. Ever since I started contributing I always found more and more places which were offering localization, but obviously the list never gets completed. There is always something left to be added. I therefore would love to see a checklist for volunteers who could volunteer in developing support for their own languages, e.g., consider the following support tools for Marathi available as of now (2022-07-20):

### Fonts

1. Unicode fonts available in TeX distributions: [Shobhika](https://ctan.org/pkg/shobhika), [Eczar](https://ctan.org/pkg/eczar), [Mukta, Baloo, Modak, Jaini](https://ctan.org/pkg/ektype-tanka)
2. LuaLaTeX renderer - Harfbuzz

### Translations

1. [`gloss-marathi.ldf`](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/blob/master/tex/gloss-marathi.ldf) from package `polyglossia`
2. [`babel-mr.ini`](https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/main/locale/mr/babel-mr.ini) from package `babel`

### Packages

1. [`marathi`](https://ctan.org/pkg/marathi)

### Manuals

1. [`latex-mr`](https://ctan.org/pkg/latex-mr)
2. https://learnlatex.org/mr

---

Now this was just a small example and not an exhaustive list of what actually is available for Marathi. Can we have a comprehensive checklist which the contributors can refer to while developing the support for their languages? I know there will be some language-specific things which will differ, but I am sure there will be some things which all languages would need. Feel free to mention pending/to-do works here in a checklist format.

PS: Feel free to point out works available for Marathi which I missed out.

Comment: I think this kind of question is in principle a good idea (although there's often some resistance to big-list type questions). If it is done it would be better to have the question be generic and have one answer per language. Maybe move this question to meta to see if people think it's a good idea?  In its present form it's not really a question for the main site since it's more of an answer than a question.

Comment: I suggest to put what you want first. E.g. changing the title into e.g. „Seeking volunteers to … Marathi …“.

Comment: I must try again to get codemirror integrated at learnlatex

Comment: This looks like something for a Wiki. You might want to add information for Marathi to this page: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Specific_languages The page has some general info about Polyglossia and Babel, and then language-specific information for 24 languages / language groups.

Comment: @AlanMunn I didn't intend it to make it an answer. The list for Marathi was supposed to serve only as an example. If that makes you feel it is a self-answer kinda post, I am sorry. I can move that part as answer if you want. Would that look like a better question to you then? I don't know how to export questions to Meta? Shall I just delete this one and copy-paste it on Meta?

Comment: @MS-SPO that is not at all what I want from this question. Please don't misinterpret it. The expectation is exactly what I have written in the title. Also with this title volunteers of other languages can easily find the question online. Anything specific to Marathi would discourage them to reach here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes ;) I will wait!

Comment: Haven't we had this discussion before? Yes, we have: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14095/creating-resources-for-a-currently-unsupported-language

Comment: Thanks @Ingmar, I had missed it, I don't mind accepting that this is a duplicate question as philosophically my objective is exactly the same, but the accepted answer there looks a bit old and doesn't seem to have a few things. Hence I feel the new language-features need some attention again :)

Comment: Since it's a community wiki, everybody can go and make the thread better … It does have some useful information, I think, might just need an update.

Comment: @Ingmar The accepted answer in the last link is a bit outdated, because it excludes XeTeX from `babel`.

Comment: Agreed, but I still think it would be best to add new answers there, or maybe update existing ones. As I've said: community wiki.

Comment: Thanks @all I will follow that thread and see if can get more up-to-date information.