# What fonts can I use for writing in Cyrillic in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, cyrillic

What other fonts are available to write in Cyrillic in LaTeX beside **T2A**, **T2B**, **T2C**?

Comment: The anwers to [Cyrillic in (La)TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/816/cyrillic-in-latex), which deal with different ways to use Cyrillic in (La)TeX and their pros and cons, might also help you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For multilingual typesetting it seems plausible to use modern TrueType or OpenType fonts, which often contain glyphs for many Unicode character ranges including Cyrillic. Some of the available fonts were made with TeX in mind or even using the original Knuth's Computer Modern as a basis. Some fonts are already included in TeX distributions.

To load a TTF/OTF font, one needs the XeTeX or LuaTeX engines. A LaTeX interface is provided by the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package.

Here's a list of some relevant fonts in no particular order:

- The [Computer Modern Unicode](http://ctan.org/pkg/cm-unicode) fonts contain many Cyrillic glyphs and are a good choice to substitute the default Computer Modern.
- The [Linux Libertine](http://ctan.org/pkg/libertine) fonts are also commonly used.
- The [Liberation](https://fedorahosted.org/liberation-fonts/) fonts are a free metric-compatible (meaning that the characters have same dimensions) alternatives to the Times New Roman, Arial and Courier New families.
- One can also use the Microsoft fonts directly. On non-Windows systems the [corefonts](http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/) pack might be useful (most likely already in your Linux distribution if you use one).

Comment: CM Unicode is not intended for latex, I suppose. Only for xelatex and lualatex.

Comment: @Igor Thanks. I rewrote the text to have better structure and clarity.

Comment: I referenced this question to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106789/why-does-usepackaget2afontenc-take-over