# How to typeset Cyrillic characters in tikzpicture nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, cyrillic

So I have this tikzpicture environment (dot2texi-generated):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,line join=bevel,]
%%
\node (а) at (5bp,51bp) [draw,ellipse] {а};
  \node (б) at (5bp,5bp) [draw,ellipse] {б};
  \draw [->] (а) ..controls (5bp,39.554bp) and (5bp,29.067bp)  .. (б);
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

with Cyrillic "а" and "б" nodes. pdfLaTeX, though, gives me the following error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \T2A\cyra 
l.4 \node (а) at (5bp,51bp) [draw,ellipse] {а};
```

So the question is: how to use Cyrillic characters in tikzpicture nodes?

**UPD**:

I should've actually include contents of original `dot2tex` environment. Andrey has given the basic idea of a possible solution: instead of

```
\begin{dot2tex}[]
  digraph { "а" -> "б" };
\end{dot2tex}
```

one can use:

```
\begin{dot2tex}[]
  digraph { a [label="а"]; b [label="б"]; a -> b }
\end{dot2tex}
```

Comment: You can't use Cyrillic characters in node names with pdfTeX. See this answer for a more elaborate discussion and possible solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24969/use-cyrillic-characters-in-the-table-of-contents-with-pdfbookmark

Comment: <sub>Too long for a comment</sub> You can't use special characters in the node names because they must be used in contexts where TeX needs to see only string of characters, while a cyrillic `б`, for instance, is translated by LaTeX into its internal representation, which is `\cyrb`, which in turn is subject to further processing that ultimately is transformed into `\char"E1` (where hexadecimal E1 is the letter position in the T2A encoding) and this is disallowed in those contexts. This wouldn't happen with a Unicode savvy engine such as `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Comment: You can post your addition as a self-answer; I've added another comment which tries to explain what's going on.

Comment: Will do (I have to wait 8 hours to post answers to my own questions until I have 100 rep).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should distinguish between a node *name* and a node *label*.  The first is how TeX references a node, and must be in ASCII.  The second is how TeX presents the node, and may be anything TeX understands.  See here:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,line join=bevel,]
%%
\node (Moscow) at (5bp,51bp) [draw,ellipse] {Москва};
  \node (SPb) at (5bp,5bp) [draw,ellipse] {Санкт-Петербург};
  \draw [->] (Moscow) ..controls (5bp,39.554bp) and (5bp,29.067bp)  .. (SPb);
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had thoughts on posting my addition to the question as a self-answer, but your explanation is much more detailed.