# Trying to make good looking comments to law in Russian

Tags: fonts, cyrillic

Suppose, I have a Russian text: quotes from law and my comments. And I want to put the comments in a such way, that:

1. the reader can easily distinguish comments from the text of the law
2. it won't distract the attention too much from the main text

Something like this:

[image]

What I achieved so far is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\\\hfill\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-0.5cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item  \textbf{\textit{#1}}
\end{itemize}
\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}
\end{minipage}\\
}
\begin{document}

Текст текст текст
\note{Мое важное замечание}
Текст текст текст
\end{document}
```

Generating this:

[image]

I think, that bold italic it's too distracting.

So, I tried OpenSans font, suggested by egreg here: [Why does \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} take over?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106789/why-does-usepackaget2afontenc-take-over):

```
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\\\hfill\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-0.5cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item {\fontfamily{fos}\selectfont \footnotesize #1}
\end{itemize}
\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}
\end{minipage}\\
}
```

[image]

This is better, but when I tried to make it italic, it reverted to computer modern:

```
\item {\fontfamily{fos}\selectfont \it #1}
```

[image]

How can I generate something, looking like the model text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\it` is obsolete and should not be used in newer document precisely because its behavior is confusing: indeed it reverts the font attributes to normal and then applies `\itshape`. Use instead

```
\item {\fontfamily{fos}\itshape #1}
```

(`\itshape` does a `\selectfont` internally, so this command is not needed).

Do you really need a `minipage`? I guess that

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\newcommand{\note}[1]{%
  \begin{itemize}
    \item  \fontfamily{fos}\itshape #1
  \end{itemize}
}
\begin{document}

Текст текст текст
\note{Мое важное замечание}
Текст текст текст
\end{document}
```

is simpler.

Comment: minipage just removed extra vertical margins for itemize

Comment: @user4035 You can use facilities of `enumitem` to suppress the vertical space.