# How to typeset Cyrillic characters with the XeLaTeX engine?

Tags: cyrillic

The Cyrillic characters in pdf are not appear if using the XeLaTeX (from [Why does \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} take over?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106789/why-does-usepackaget2afontenc-take-over/106826#106826)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{PTSans-TLF}\normalfont
\section{PTSans}

Todd is a cat. \textcyrillic{у меня есть машина. я очень харашо.}


\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fds}\normalfont
\section{Droid}

Todd is a cat. \textcyrillic{у меня есть машина. я очень харашо.}


\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fco}\normalfont
\section{Comforta}

Todd is a cat. \textcyrillic{у меня есть машина. я очень харашо.}


\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fca}\normalfont
\section{Cantarell}

Todd is a cat. \textcyrillic{у меня есть машина. я очень харашо.}


\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{iwona}\normalfont
\section{Iwona}

Todd is a cat. \textcyrillic{у меня есть машина. я очень харашо.}


\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fos}\normalfont
\section{OpenSans}

Todd is a cat. \textcyrillic{у меня есть машина. я очень харашо.}

\end{document}
```

**-------EDIT--------**

I need to get these aims:

1. XeLaTeX engine
2. use the condensed iwona fonts in mathematics environment
3. use the condensed iwona fonts for main text (including both Latin and Cyrillic letters)
4. use the `txtt` fonts typesetting URL
5. use the `txtt` fonts instead default `ttfamily`

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{txtt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[condensed,math]{iwona}

\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\url{http://google.com}\\
\texttt{TXTT-FONTS}\\
\textcyrillic{Ломоно́сов}\\
$\sin^2 x+1$\\
today\\
\end{document}
```

Maybe I'm missing something, so I'd be happy to be pushed in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I think, this MWE is written for PDFLaTeX and not for XeLaTeX. Do you need XeLaTeX? Which font do you want to use? You should have a look on the package `fontspec`.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thanks. See my edited question, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `txtt` font is not suitable for usage with `fontspec`; also, `inputenc` should not be used and you have to select a main font with support for Cyrillic, as the default Latin Modern fonts haven't it.

The `iwona` package should be loaded before `fontspec` and `fontenc` is useless in this context. Then you need to choose Iwona with `fontspec` commands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[condensed,math]{iwona}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Iwona Cond}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}

\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\url{http://google.com}  

\textcyrillic{Ломоно́сов}  

$\sin^2 x+1$  

today
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But why don't you choose the `iwona` font for main text? I need the Cyrillic characters typesetted in iwona fonts.

Comment: @nameabc Fixed.

Comment: to get this to work on Debian I needed to do as suggested in  https://github.com/matze/mtheme/issues/280#issuecomment-454041741