# How to mix characters from different languages in LaTeX?

Tags: errors, characters

I cannot mix characters from different languages ​​in one document. When I add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, there are problems with the cyrillic characters. When I add `T2A`, there are problems with other characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
aşçęÐпщ
\end{document}
```

T1:

```
Unicode character п (U+043F)
(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

T1,T2A:

```
Command \DH unavailable in encoding T2A.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cedilla and ogonek are in the T2A encoded fonts, so LaTeX is able to compose them to the main glyph (T2A contains the latin letters). However `\DH` cannot be composed.

Declare that it is, by default, in T1 encoding.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}

\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\DH}{T1}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
aşçęÐпщ
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
aşçęÐпщ
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Does this mean that there is no chance of doing this on a regular LaTeX?

Comment: @KesantieluDasefern If someone has done the hard work. 256-glyph limit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120085/good-reference-for-learning-how-fonts-works?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370324/why-use-both-fontenc-and-inputenc-in-the-same-document?rq=1 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106789/why-does-usepackaget2afontenc-take-over

Comment: @KesantieluDasefern As @Cicada already pointed out: No. `xelatex` and `lualatex` are perfectly stable and the best way to go