# Russian, Cyrillic in TeX

Tags: languages, babel, cyrillic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cyrillic in (La)TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/816/cyrillic-in-latex)

I want to add a quote in Russian to my thesis. It is pretty long, so I wouldn't like to use as input any transliteration based method, basically because I wouldn't get the right hyphenation (and because writing in Cyrillic should be very possible). Codes like

```
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
```

didn't do the trick. Neither did it by changing the input encoding. Am I missing something before compiling? Can somebody post a short TeX-code? If it helps, I'm using Kile.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/816/cyrillic-in-latex. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you, in particular ["Mixing cyrillic and latin letters"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/838). If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\begin{document}

This quotation is in Russian:
\begin{quote}
  \selectlanguage{russian}
  Я помню чудное мгновенье:\\
  Передо мной явилась ты,\\
  Как мимолетное виденье,\\
  Как гений чистой красоты.
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

[image]