# Xetex and Times New Roman font

Tags: fonts, xetex

I want to create a document using latex, but I discovered that latex only works with plain ascii, and my native language is not English :) So I tried xetex instead (with example from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX)). The problem is, I do not have the font that example requires.

What should I add to the beginning section of my .tex file to get a proper font - Times New Roman for example?

Comment: What is your native language (if you don't mind me asking)?

Comment: LaTeX works with a huge number of alphabets and languages. Probably also with your language.

Comment: Check the XeTeX answer to this question [How do I use a particular font for a small section of my document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/2693) (which covers font use in XeTeX thoroughly).

Comment: @ThorstenDonig - Russian, and I checked - latex just outputs blanks instead of the text.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/816/cyrillic-in-latex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use any otf or ttf font installed on your system. I tried the code you linked to both with "Times New Roman" and "Minion Pro"
My Times New Roman seems not to have oldstyle nums, but Minio does

Comment: Can you please post the \setmainfont expression you used? I seem to be completely lost - it is unable to find the needed font file.

Comment: `setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Minion Pro}`

Comment: @Rogach: It won't help you very much if we sent you a lot of `\setmainfont`-commands that works on our systems. What matters are the font *you* have on your system and their names. So you should at first give some informations like your OS and which of your system fonts you actually want to use.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I am a newbie, so I do not understand the syntax by heart yet. For example, I did not know that font name needed to be inputted with spaces - and that command worked for me.

Comment: @Rochach: I didn't expected you to know the syntax but to give more details. As a newbie you can make a lot errors and it is much easier to help you if you actually show what you are doing. E.g. the example on the wikipedia page you linked to in your question contains `\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}`- a font name with spaces. So one would need a very good christal ball to guess that your problem was due to missing spaces. If you had shown your code it would have been easy to see.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Yes, I agree with you :) I will post code from now on.