# Cyrillic support

Tags: cyrillic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cyrillic in (La)TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/816/cyrillic-in-latex)

I'm typesetting a bilingual dictionary, which includes a number of words written in the Cyrillic script. I've tried everything recommended on support sites and in the guides, but I cannot get any Cyrillic text to come out. Using the `babel` package has failed, specifying font encodings, `\foreignlanguage{}{}` ... nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have you tried all the options in [Cyrillic in (La)TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/816) ? The way it is right now, your question is a duplicate of that question. If you're struggling with one specific solution that you'd like to use, please try to specify your question to that solution, add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, and also include any error messages you get.