# How to turn the hyphenation on?

Tags: hyphenation, babel

I was looking for a clue on how to use cyrillics in an english text and vice versa. Finally I found a solution here: [Cyrillic in (La)TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/816/cyrillic-in-latex)

The solution looks like this

```
\documentclass[article, 12pt]{article} 

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
%\usepackage{cmap}
```

However it does not hyphenate the russian part of the text. How can I help this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have you changed the language in-document with `\selectlanguage{russion}` or the `otherlanguage` environment?

Comment: no...i am not sure it will do...i wrote an article in english, now i would like to render it in russian...so that it is not a fragment of the text that is to be in cyrillics but the whole text. however, while translating it an moving back and forth i d like to have both laguages active...but i ll try your tip about \selectlanguage    thanks

Comment: well, i m answering my own question...It's the order in babel that matters. with 
english first, russian second the hyphenation defect has gone....I found this in the \selectlanguage discussion...Thanks, Qrrbrbirlbel!

Comment: This is a very basic part of how `babel` works: I doubt the question will help others, so closing.