# How to make dvi show cyrillic letters?

Tags: font-encodings, cyrillic, dvi-mode

I could copy the sentence "МАТЕМАТИЧКИ ВЕСНИК" into the LaTeX, however when I press the `dvi`, it does not show in the `dvi`. How to make the dvi show the sentence "МАТЕМАТИЧКИ ВЕСНИК"?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. My guess would be that you need some package that can process cyrillic (?) letters, like `\usepackage{polyglossia}`
`\setmainlanguage{russian}` or `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
`\usepackage[russian]{babel}`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/816/cyrillic-in-latex

Comment: Have you tried converting the _dvi_ to _pdf_ or generating _pdf_ from _tex_?

Comment: No. I am editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a small text in Russian, perhaps the cheapest method is to use the OT2 encoding; in this way no juggling with input encodings is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\russtext}[1]{%
  {\fontencoding{OT2}\fontfamily{wncyr}\selectfont#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\russtext{Matematichki Vesnik}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[koi8-r]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\section{Раздел}
Текст на русском языке
\end{document}
```

I recommend you to read first some books about latex and after that try to work with it.

Comment: Where should I put it in?

Comment: Just latex it: `latex file.tex`.

Comment: It cannot operate:(

Comment: Change encoding of file to koi8-r or change `[koi8-r]` to `[utf8]` in option of `\usepackage{inputenc}`. But i recommend you first to read a couple of books about latex.