# Use fonts in LaTeX from directory C:/Windows/Fonts

Tags: fonts, cyrillic

I'd like to use `Palatino` font in LaTeX, but there are no cyrillic symbols in the `mathpazo` package. But I can easily type cyrillic symbols with `Palatino` font in MS Word. So, is there any method for using Windows system fonts in LaTeX?

**UPD**
I tried XeLaTeX and `fontspec` package, but it doesn't work with cyrillic symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}

\begin{document}
Hello, world!
Привет, мир!
\end{document}
```

Should I add some commands for cyrillic symbols?

Comment: If you use xelatex or lualatex then you can use system fonts (search for examples of the `fontspec` package on this site).

Comment: possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/816/cyrillic-in-latex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, added MWE for XeLaTeX.

Comment: @Alvar Your MWE works for me with xelatex (texlive 2012) perhaps you need to post the log file you get for that, are any errors reported.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I'm using MikTeX. Errors from log file:
    `Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 8 replaced by U+FFFD.`
    `Missing character: There is no � in font Palatino Linotype/ICU:script=latn;la
nguage=DFLT;!`

I'll try TeXLive, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that your file is saved as utf-8 rather than in an older cyrillic encoding. The error message would indicate it is not in utf8 (I can't tell as it is in utf8 by the time it is posted to the website but that isn't quite the same thing)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you are right, I checked and converted in another editor. Now it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok glad you got it working, we will probably close this as "too localised"  rather than leave it unanswered.