# Package babel Error: Unknown option `francais'

Tags: errors, babel

I recently updated my operating system from Ubuntu 13.04 to Ubuntu 13.10.

Since then, I am facing difficulties compiling my TeX code in which the french babel package is called. Please note that all my sources were compiling **very fine before** the system upgrade.

However, now, given the following header:

```
  \usepackage[francais]{babel}
```

I receive the following error:

> ```
> ! Package babel Error: Unknown option `francais'. Either you misspelled it
> ```

What should I do? **Please note** that if I remove this part of code (`\usepackage[francais]{babel}`), everything is compiling well. I also tried it with `french`, and I receive the same result.

Thank you in advance for your help.

---

**MINIMUM WORKING EXAMPLE :**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
This is a MINIMUM WORKING EXAMPLE.
\end{document}
```

> ```
> ! Package babel Error: Unknow option `francais'. Either you misspelled it
> ```

Comment: It's `french` not `francais`

Comment: @YuppieNetworking : Unfortunately, it's not working either with `french`. I receive the same error.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to specify that it is not working with the `french` option, and add all your preamble for us to see if there is some problems in it.

Comment: @LudovicC. It worked with `francais` before the upgrade. And only this line gives this error. If I remove it, there is no further error.

Comment: @Martingal Why do you need this package? Are you trying to typeset letters like ç as in *Français*? And do you use pdflatex or Xelatex?

Comment: @Alenanno : Yes, I need that package, otherwise I wouldn't be asking here ... Especially when it's french reports.

Comment: @YuppeNetworking: in fact the original name of the option is `frenchb`. `french`and `francais`are both aliases of this name. A few years ago there used to be an autonomous `french`package which did a similar job and could be used with `babel`. (This package still exists under the name `eFrench` after having been a shareware named `FrenchPro` for a while). hence possible confusions and the choice of `frenchb` for the french option of babel. In recent distributions however, the names `frenchb`, `french`and `francais` as options for babel should lead to the same results.

Comment: @LudovicC. For future reference, please do not ask users to "add all your preamble for us to see if there is some problems in it". I refer to the following guide on how to write a [_minimal_ working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/9077).

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The complete error message is:

```
! Package babel Error: Unknown option `francais'. Either you misspelled it
(babel)                or the language definition file francais.ldf was not found.
```

Package file `babel.sty` supports `francais` since a very long time, thus the second line of the error message applies very likely:

The organization of the `babel` language files has recently changed. The language files (`.ldf`, ...) go into separate TeX distribution packages. For example, option `francais` loads `frenchb.ldf`:

- TeX Live puts the latter in the distribution package `babel-french`. It needs to be installed, if you are using `tlmgr`, the package manager of TeX Live.
- In Ubuntu *saucy* there is a package `texlive-lang-french` that contains `frenchb.ldf` ([file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/all/texlive-lang-french/filelist)). Install it, if you are using TeX Live of Ubuntu.

Comment: Your second proposal solved my problem. Thank you very much for your help. I have no idea why it was removed when upgrading the system. Anyway, thanks again !

Comment: FWIW: In Fedora 18+, packages like `texlive-babel-german` contains the relevant files.

Comment: It works in the same way in Ubuntu 16.04 for italian language: just need to install the package `texlive-lang-italian`.

Answer (score 64):

I had the same error while trying to generate the pdf files from `lyx`. I did run `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-french` and the error was resolved. Now working fine

**Update:**
These packages have become obsolete; texlive-lang-european should be installed now:

`sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-european`

Comment: Just a note: I encountered this issue with German, but `texlive-lang-european` did not resolve the issue. Only `texlive-lang-german` did.

Comment: you forgot an install after apt-get

Comment: Installing apt-get install texlive-lang-french solved my problem.

Comment: In the CTAN repo the package name is slightly different, install with `tlmgr install collection-langeuropean`.

Comment: collection-langeuropean contains "minor" languages, and does not include at least: German, Italian, French, Spanish, Polish, Portuguese.

Answer (score 8):

Exactly same issue here for various languages like: `\usepackage[dutch]{babel}`

A way of solving: Open: Ubuntu Software Center and install: texlive-lang-all

But what still changed is that in case you change the language in the `\usepackage[english]{babel}` you have to remove the temporary latex files before latex-ing again. But with that remark every works again as before.

Comment: Installing `texlive-lang-all` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

The solution for the error prompted for `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` :

> ! Package babel Error: Unknown option `spanish'. Either you misspelled
>   it

Install the texlive-babel-spanish package via yum/dnf:

```
sudo dnf install texlive-babel-spanish
```

Comment: This package doesn't exist for Ubuntu with `apt-get`, as with other languages the command needed is `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-spanish`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for the Spanish language, only after reading I came to the conclusion that I had to install all the packages, and so I did for Elementary OS from the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install texlive-full texmaker
```

---

Yo tuve el mismo problema para el lenguaje español, unicamente luego de leer llegué a la conclusión que debía instalar todos los paquetes, y así hice para Elementary OS desde la terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install texlive-full texmaker
```

[image: Screenshot of Texmaker]

Answer (score 0):

I found this post looking for the spanish version of this error, i.e.:

Package babel Error: Unknown option `spanish'.

To solve do:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-spanish
```

(Works on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer [here (duplicate question)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167077/package-babel-error-unknown-option-ngerman?noredirect=1&lq=1).
For me on different Ubuntu derivates, this did the trick:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-german
```

(don't forget the `install` as in [egreg's comment there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167077/package-babel-error-unknown-option-ngerman?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment384065_167077), where I have this from)

For Fedora/Debian please use

```
sudo dnf install texlive-babel-german
```

Of course, you can replace german with your needed language, dutch, spanish or francais, as in the other answers.

Apparently (as stated [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142358/110394)),
**these packages have become obsolete; texlive-lang-european should be installed now:**

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-european
```