# Package babel Error: Unknown option `ngerman'

Tags: errors, babel, german

I've tried to create German quotation marks in LaTeX, but after compiling with `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`, I get this error:

```
! Package babel Error: Unknow option `ngerman'. Either you misspelled it
(babel) or the language definition file ngerman.ldf was not found.
```

The solution  "Partei"' doesn't work at all and the alternative `\glqq` only works with the `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`...

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\normalfont}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

can anybody help me please? I have to turn in my paper next week...

Here's my "extended example":

I want to have German quotation marks. Normally, there are two possibilities to accomplish that:

1. either you do it this way: "`Partei"' and compile it. 
   Unfortunately, this does not work any more (it has worked for my last paper, but I didn't change anything in my TeXmaker)
2. you can write: \glqq Partei\grqq and then you get German quotation marks in case you have installed the \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} or \usepackage{german}, but with both usepackaged I get the error described above.

Normally, I work with TeXmaker on Linux Ubuntu.

Do you need any more information? I'm not quite an expert on this field, sorry...

Comment: Can you extend your code to a [compilable minimal example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html)? That way we are all on the same page and know what's going on.

Comment: Are you using MiKTeX? If so, go to the Settings, Languages, and make sure the entries with `(n)german` are checked.

Comment: The German orthography reform became official in 1996 and, IIRC, the `ngerman` module for `babel` was issued shortly thereafter. What TeX distribution are you using? If it's on a GNU/Linux box, you may have to install German language support.

Comment: How do I install the German language support in Linux?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It's working now! Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: for Fedora I had to install `sudo dnf install texlive-babel-german`

Comment: I believe it should be `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-german`.