# spanish option for babel

Tags: miktex, babel, spanish

I recently updated my **Miktex 2.9** and when I tried to compile my files I get the following error, which I didn't have before:

> package babel error: unknown option spanish. Either you misspelled it
> or the language definition file spanish.ldf was not found.

This is a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228):

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,mathrsfs,enumerate,epsfig,fullpage,pst-grad,pst-plot}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document} Esta es una prueba. \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The organization of `babel` has changed. The languages has been separated into separate distribution packages and are now independently maintained. In MiKTeX you have to install `babel-spanish` to get `babel`'s `spanish`.

Related: [Package babel Error: Unknown option `francais'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139700/16967)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer at [this related or duplicate question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167077/package-babel-error-unknown-option-ngerman?noredirect=1&lq=1).

For me on different **Ubuntu** derivates, this did the trick:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-spanish %in my case -german
```

<sup>(don't forget the `install` as in [egreg's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142358/110394) [where I have this from](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167077/package-babel-error-unknown-option-ngerman?noredirect=1&lq=1))</sup>

For **Fedora/Debian** please use

```
sudo dnf install texlive-babel-spanish %in my case -german
```

Of course, you can replace *spanish/german* with your needed language, dutch, francais or another one.

### Edit/Update:

Apparently, as stated in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142358/110394), these packages have become obsolete; `texlive-lang-european` should be installed now instead:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-european
```

<sup>Fore a more technical explanation see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139707/110394)</sup>