# Texmaker - I can't compile any .tex (moderncv, other)

Tags: miktex, texlive, texmaker, ubuntu

I've worked with TeXmaker for several years now, but it doesn't work anymore. Last month, I had to completely reboot my computer. I use now Ubuntu 16.04LTS, which is a dual boot.

So I installed Texmaker (`sudo apt-get install texmaker`)... and surprise surprise: i cannot make compilations of `files.tex`
The fact is that I can't compile my own files, which were compiled by my own laptop.

I have several issues, listed below:

- *Use of moderncv:* cannot find the file `fontawesome.sty`. I could compile this `cv.tex` before, though. I copy it in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/`... But still doesn't work.
- *Normal use:* I tried to write a short and simple text. I also tried to compile some of my previous works (only writing things). The package `babel` is not recognized -> `frenchb`, `french`, `français`, and even `english` are not considered as languages.

So here I am. **I've got plenty of `files.tex` that compiled well before, but not anymore.**

You would be very nice if you could help me with this stuff.

Comment: Just go to Package Manger Directory and install the desired packages, to make it behave normally.

Comment: Packages must be installed on the root of the laptop, is that right?
Hum... Why are these packages absent from this configuration of texmaker ?

Comment: `TeXmaker` is just an IDE, that is a software with embedded features that makes it more easy to use that a plain notepad (e.g. `gedit`). However, it is just a more convenient way to write the source-file of your document, nothing more. To process it (i.e. generating a PDF from your `.tex` file, **you need to install `(La)TeX` software on your computer**. I recommend you to install it via TeXlive (but from [the sources](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) in order to have the 2016 version, what is not the case with `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`).

Comment: @Loïc how about the minimal example `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} foo \end{document}` does this compile?  If not, likely you need to (re)install your tex distribution (i.e. texlive).

Comment: @Dai Bowen: This minimal example works. It compiles.

Comment: @ebo : I use miktex. If i'm not wrong, it is another software which permits to compile. May i have to install Texlive too?

Comment: @Loïc if the MWE does compile, it means that you have a `TeX` engine installed. So it's not the issue I thought about. I thought that MikTeX was for MSWindows only, but I was apparently wrong: you can [build an unix version from the sources](http://miktex.org/howto/build-unx). So there is no *need* to install TeXlive, even if using MikTeX is i*m*ho less common on a Gnu/Linux OS.

Comment: @ebo : I've just noticed that i had a folder named Texlive. So it may be the Tex engine I use :)

Comment: @Loïc then you should have a look at the first line of the created `.log` file to know which engine you use.

Comment: .log : This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.7.15)  14 SEP 2016 16:11

So i use texlive, without knowing it :)

Comment: Thus, I suggest you to uninstall MikTeX, and do a fresh install of TeXlive (moreover, you'll then update from the 2015 to the 2016 version and so benefit from package updates)

Comment: If reinstalling doesn't seem to do the job, try following [How to remove everything related to TeX Live for fresh install on Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95483/106162) and [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/106162).  The `moderncv` problem may be font-installation specific but `babel` problems are (likely) something else.

Comment: @Dai Bowen: Everything seems to be ok. The file .log refers to LiveTex2016... And everyhing compiles! (CV, docs..)

Thanks for your patience ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because problem was solved by reinstalling the software.

Answer (score 1):

Based on information detailed in comments, I suggest you to [do a fresh install](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) of the [new release of `TeXlive`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).

Note Dai Bowen's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329515/texmaker-i-cant-compile-any-tex-moderncv-other/329547#comment807583_329515) hereinabove:

> If reinstalling doesn't seem to do the job, try following [How to
>   remove everything related to TeX Live for fresh install on Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95483/64454) and
>   [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/64454). The `moderncv`
>   problem may be font-installation specific but `babel` problems are
>   (likely) something else.

Comment: Deleted, installed, and PATH done. But when i compile the MWE, i have the same version in my .log (2015). And of course, more complex compilations don't work at all.

Comment: Babel problem is solved using this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139700/package-babel-error-unknown-option-francais

Comment: I copy the 'fontawesome.sty' file into /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/. I run \updmap and... Not the same issue when compiling. Now, the file 'fontawesomesymbols-generix.tex' is missing. I tried the same technic with this file, but unfortunately, it doesn't work. 
I have the impression that the moderncv package i have is not working well...

PS: \moderncvstyle{casual} does not work, but \moderncvstyle{classic} works.

Comment: @Loïc well, it seems somehow strange to me. To force your system to run TeXlive 2016 when compiling, you could uninstall TeXlive 2015 (if your sure your TL2016 install is full and working).