# English hyphenation works well but French does not

Tags: hyphenation, polyglossia

I observe something strange with the management of hyphenation by Polyglossia on my configuration. It seems that the English hyphenation settings are correctly loaded and applied, but not the other languages as French (what is my case, but I also tried German or Spanish, the result is the same). In the last cases, there is no automatic hyphenation at all.

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{french}

\begin{document}
Alors de contexte international conjuguant la crise de international représentation politique,
le international numérique des sociétés et l’affirmation de la infrastructures des populations
par les infrastructures, mon projet infrastructures recherche poursuit comme finalité de 
\textbf{temps la transformation du modernes parlementaire dans le temps pour de le suscitant}.
\end{document}
```

Which gives :

[image]

If I switch to `\setmainlanguage{english}`, I get :

[image]

How do you explain such a behavior ? How can I enable French hyphenation ? Did I miss something ?

**Solution :**

Thanks to Moewe ! The French lang package was simply missing : `texlive-lang-french`. The European one did not suffice.

**Edit :**

Here is the log :

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.3.28)  28 MAR 2020 16:27
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 29 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
Package: polyglossia 2015/03/25 v1.42.4 Alternative to Babel for XeLaTeX and Lu
aLaTeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2018/02/11 v2.5e e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count87
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty
Package: makecmds 2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count88
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2018/02/21 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2018/02/21 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count89
\l_tmpa_int=\count90
\l_tmpb_int=\count91
\g_tmpa_int=\count92
\g_tmpb_int=\count93
\g__intarray_font_int=\count94
\g__prg_map_int=\count95
\c_log_iow=\count96
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count97
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count98
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count99
\l__iow_indent_int=\count100
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count101
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count109
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count110
\l__sort_length_int=\count111
\l__sort_min_int=\count112
\l__sort_top_int=\count113
\l__sort_max_int=\count114
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count115
\l__sort_block_int=\count116
\l__sort_begin_int=\count117
\l__sort_end_int=\count118
\l__sort_A_int=\count119
\l__sort_B_int=\count120
\l__sort_C_int=\count121
\l__tl_build_start_index_int=\count122
\l__tl_build_index_int=\count123
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count124
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count125
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count126
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count127
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count128
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count129
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count130
\l__regex_balance_int=\count131
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count132
\l__regex_mode_int=\count133
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count134
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count135
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count136
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count137
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count138
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count139
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count140
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count141
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count142
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count143
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count144
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count145
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count146
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count147
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count148
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count149
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count150
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count151
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count152
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count153
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count154
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count155
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count156
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count157
\l__regex_step_int=\count158
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count159
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count160
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count161
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count162
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count163
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count164
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count165
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count166
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen109
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen110
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen111
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen112
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen113
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen114
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box32
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen118
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen119
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen120
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen121
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen123
\c_empty_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen124
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def
File: l3xdvidpfmx.def 2017/03/18 v L3 Experimental driver: xdvipdfmx
\g__driver_image_int=\count167
\l__driver_tmp_box=\box41
))
Package: xparse 2018/02/21 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count168
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count169
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count170
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count171
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count172
)
Package: fontspec 2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count173
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count174
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count175
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count176
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count177
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count178
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count179
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count180
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen134
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen136
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def
File: tuenc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TU on input line 82.
))
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \fontspec with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 542.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmainfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 546.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setsansfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 550.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmonofont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 554.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathrm with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 558.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setboldmathrm with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 562.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathsf with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 566.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathtt with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 570.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setromanfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 574.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfamily with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 578.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontface with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 582.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \defaultfontfeatures with sig. 't+om' on line 586.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeatures with sig. 'm' on line 590.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeature with sig. 'm' on line 594.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 598.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newAATfeature with sig. 'mmmm' on line 602.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newopentypefeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 606.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newICUfeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 610.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 614.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeatureoption with sig. 'mmm' on line 618.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontscript with sig. 'mm' on line 622.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontlanguage with sig. 'mm' on line 626.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareFontsExtensions with sig. 'm' on line 630.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \IfFontFeatureActiveTF with sig. 'mmm' on line 634.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingCommand with sig. 'mO{}m' on line 3632.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingAccent with sig. 'mm' on line 3638.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingSymbol with sig. 'mm' on line 3644.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingComposite with sig. 'mmm' on line 3650.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingCompositeCommand with sig. 'mmm' on line 3656.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareUnicodeEncoding with sig. 'mm' on line 3681.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareSymbol with sig. 'm' on line 3687.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareAccent with sig. 'm' on line 3693.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareCommand with sig. 'm' on line 3699.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareComposite with sig. 'mm' on line 3706.
.................................................

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 3891.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 3896.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 3901.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 3906.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 3936.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 3961.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \- on input line 4015.
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/redefine-command"
. 
. Redefining command \oldstylenums with sig. 'm' on line 4110.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \liningnums with sig. 'm' on line 4114.
.................................................
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\xpg@normalclass=\XeTeXcharclass1
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-french.ldf
File: gloss-french.ldf polyglossia: module for french


Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `French'
(polyglossia)                I will use \language=\l@nohyphenation instead on i
nput line 10.

\l@french = a dialect from \language\l@nohyphenation 

Package polyglossia Warning: \setlocalhyphenmin useless for unhyphenated langua
ge french on input line 10.

\french@punctthin=\XeTeXcharclass2
\french@punctthick=\XeTeXcharclass3
\french@punctguillstart=\XeTeXcharclass4
\french@punctguillend=\XeTeXcharclass5
)
Package polyglossia Info: Default language is french.
 (./test.aux

Package polyglossia Warning: \english@font@rm is not defined on input line 2.


Package polyglossia Warning: \english@language is not defined on input line 2.

)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
.................................................
. fontspec info: "setup-math"
. 
. Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).
.................................................
\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmr/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/lmr/bx/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/bx/n on input line 7.

Overfull \hbox (19.25003pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 8--9
[]\TU/lmr/m/n/10 Alors de contexte international conjuguant la crise de interna
tional représentation
 []


Overfull \hbox (17.41003pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 8--9
\TU/lmr/m/n/10 politique, le international numérique des sociétés et l’affirmat
ion de la infrastructures
 []


Overfull \hbox (27.80673pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 8--9
\TU/lmr/m/n/10 poursuit comme finalité de \TU/lmr/bx/n/10 temps la transformati
on du modernes parlementaire
 []

[1

] (./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11084 strings out of 494440
 250617 string characters out of 6165199
 323222 words of memory out of 5000000
 14974 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 530296 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 350 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 45i,4n,36p,10431b,233s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: Can you show us the `.log` file of the French example document, please? How did you install LaTeX? (Are you using Windows, Linux or Mac OS? Are you running MikTeX or TeX live?)

Comment: @moewe : Thank for your quick answer. I've edited my post with the log. I'm under Ubuntu 18.04 and I installed LaTeX from the distribution repositories. I'm using xelatex.

Comment: Did you install the French language pack? `apt install texlive-lang-french`

Comment: OK, you're right. The European one did not suffice, I needed the specific French one. Everything works now ! Thank again !

Comment: Would you be OK with closing the question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139700/35864?

Comment: No problem ! I do that.