# How to use poetrytex with cyrillic letters

Tags: pdftex, cyrillic, tex-general, poetry

I am trying to use `poetrytex` with cyrillic letters like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{poetrytex}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\poetryheadings}{\pagestyle{myheadings} \markboth{}{}}
\begin{poem}{Title}{Author\\2014}
Мороз и солнце, день чудесный\\
The sea is calm to-night.\\
\end{poem}
\end{document}
```

But `pdflatex` generates this:

[image]

How to tell `poetrytex` package what I want?

Comment: this is not caused by poetrytex, you need to configure cyrillic support with pdflatex. see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72690/2891 for some method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the `T2A` font encoding in addition to `T1` and `babel` with options `russian, english`, plus a font that contains cyrillic glyphs. One of these, on CTAN, is `Heuristica` – an addition to Adobe Utopia, that also contains oldstyle  and superior figures:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1,T2A, T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{heuristica}%
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{poetrytex}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm]{geometry}
\newcommand*\English{\selectlanguage{english}}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}%
\renewcommand{\poetryheadings}{\pagestyle{myheadings} \markboth{}{}}
\begin{poem}{Title}{Author\\2014}
{\Russian Мороз и солнце, день чудесный} \\
{\itshape
The sea is calm to-night.}\\
\end{poem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

While with `pdflatex` you rely on LaTeX support for a given font, the choice of a font is much easier with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and the `fontspec` package, since you can use any Opentype font known to the operating system (at least for ordinary text). Also, you don't have to choose a font encoding, nor an input encoding. Here is an example compiled  with XeLaTeX that uses `Minion Pro` (available with Adobe Reader):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}%
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{poetrytex}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm]{geometry}
\newcommand*\English{\selectlanguage{english}}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\poetryheadings}{\pagestyle{myheadings} \markboth{}{}}
\begin{poem}{Title}{Author\\2014}
\textup{\Russian Мороз и солнце, день чудесный}\\
\textit{The sea is calm to-night.}
\end{poem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another beautiful font, available on CTAN is `ebgaramond`. Unfortunately it doesn't have (yet) a bold version, and it works well with `LuaLaTeX` but, for some reason, has problems with XeLaTeX (if you ask a part of the text in italic, the whole text is in italic).

**Last News:** 
The very last version of `ebgaramond.sty` (2014/07/02, not yet updated in MiKTeX) now works fine with XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont = EBGaramond12-Italic]{EBGaramond12}%
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{poetrytex}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm]{geometry}
\newcommand*\English{\selectlanguage{english}}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\poetryheadings}{\pagestyle{myheadings} \markboth{}{}}
\begin{poem}{Title}{Author\\2014}
\textup{\Russian Мороз и солнце, день чудесный}\\
\textit{The sea is calm to-night.}
\end{poem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, Bernard! Many thanks for explanation and examples.

Comment: @Pavel Morozkin: I forgot to include `Paratype` fonts as another font group that is designed with cyrillic characters (actually specifically designed for them) and has support in LaTeX.