# How to insert the letters Ɵ , Ƣ , Ə , ʐ , Қ and Ң

Tags: symbols, cyrillic

To print Ɵ , Ƣ , Ə , ʐ , Қ and Ң letters, which package and which control sequences should I use?

Comment: Have you tried this page ? http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: It’s not an exact duplicate, but I answered a similar question [here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542039/61644) I would recommend using LuaLaTeX if you can, and 8-bit fonts if you have to.

Comment: If your font contains those characters, you should just be able to paste them int your source file in text mode.

Answer (score 4):

In ConTeXt MKIV this works out-of-the-box with a font that supports Cyrillic.

```
\setupbodyfont[computer-modern-unicode]

\starttext

Ɵ , Ƣ , Ə , ʐ , Қ and Ң

\stoptext
```

[image]

---

The same is possible with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX with slightly more boilerplate.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

Ɵ , Ƣ , Ə , ʐ , Қ and Ң

\end{document}
```

The output is similar.

Comment: letters is displayed and I get this warning. Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/it' in size <10> not available(Font) Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/sl' tried instead.

Comment: is there anyway I print these letters with a comman, because I use it only once like \textschwa Ə

Answer (score 3):

According to Unicode, the letters you have are

> 1. Ɵ U+019F LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH MIDDLE TILDE
> 2. Ƣ U+01A2 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER OI
> 3. Ə U+018F LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SCHWA
> 4. ʐ U+0290 LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH RETROFLEX HOOK
> 5. Қ U+049A CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER KA WITH DESCENDER
> 6. Ң U+04A2 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER EN WITH DESCENDER

Assuming you are using pdflatex, I know of no font providing U+01A2. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gha) the letter was used by the Latin orthography of some Turkic languages, but currently other letters are used.

If you are interested in the Cyrillic script, I guess that the first letter should be a Fita

> Ѳ U+0472 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER FITA

The third letter should be

> Ә U+04D8 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER SCHWA

The fourth letter might be

> ӡ U+04E1 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ABKHASIAN DZE

The Fita, Schwa, Ka with descender and En with descender are provided by encodings T2A, T2B and T2C; the Dze is in encodings T2B and T2C.

See [Cyrillic in (La)TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/816/cyrillic-in-latex) for more information about how to enable using the letters.

Answer (score 0):

In LuaLaTeX, while I had no problems with other Azeri letters, I stucked with a capital schwa - Ə. I decided to cheat a bit, using some command for small ə, like

```
\newcommand\Ə{{\LARGE ə}}
```

and redefining all Ə's by `\Ə`