# Cyrillic letters ACM template

Tags: pdftex, unicode, font-encodings, cyrillic

I'm trying to use Cyrillic letters in the [ACM Official Master Template](https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/acm-official#.WOuOk2e1taQ). To use Cyrillic letters it is necessary to use the T2A font encoding, so I set `\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}` because I use both, English and Cyrillic fonts. Unfortunately, it crashes because other packages in this template cannot handle this kind of font encoding. Switching from `pdflatex` to `lualatex` or `xelatex` didn't work either.

In my special case I would only need one Cyrillic character, which is И.

Is it possible to use only T1 font encoding and generate a utf-8 character as this single character?

Comment: You probably want to `\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}`. This sets T1 as the default encoding and T2A as the supplemental one, instead of the other way around.

Comment: It is also possible to use a single symbol from a T2A font, but that’s really an XY problem.

Comment: Where should the character be used? In math? If so, should it be upright or italic?

Comment: Also, I believe you can compile an `acmart` document in XeLaTeX and just use Unicode.

Comment: If you’re not using the OpenType version of Libertine in XeTeX, you might need to substitute Libertinus Serif/Sans as your T2A font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know precisely what the journal you want to submit to accepts. but here’s a pared-down version of the template that adds this Cyrillic character, in both text and math mode.  Since the template states that you should use the `libertine` font package, it takes the Cyrillic alphabet from Libertinus Serif and Libertinus Sans.

```
%%%% Generic manuscript mode
\documentclass[manuscript,screuen,review]{acmart}
\usepackage{iftex}

\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{newunicodechar, substitutefont}

  \substitutefont{T2A}{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}{LibertinusSerif-TLF}
  \substitutefont{T2A}{LinuxBiolinumT-TLF}{LibertinusSans-TLF}
  \newunicodechar{И}{{\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\symbol{"C8}}}
\fi

\newcommand\mitcyrI{\mathord{\text{\rmfamily\mdseries\itshape И}}}
\newcommand\mupcyrI{\mathord{\text{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape И}}}
\newcommand\mbfitcyrI{\mathord{\text{\rmfamily\bfseries\itshape И}}}
\newcommand\mbfupcyrI{\mathord{\text{\rmfamily\bfseries\upshape И}}}
\newcommand\msfupcyrI{\mathord{\text{\sffamily\mdseries\upshape И}}}

%%
%% \BibTeX command to typeset BibTeX logo in the docs
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}

%% Rights management information.  This information is sent to you
%% when you complete the rights form.  These commands have SAMPLE
%% values in them; it is your responsibility as an author to replace
%% the commands and values with those provided to you when you
%% complete the rights form.
\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2018}
\acmYear{2018}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}

%%
%% end of the preamble, start of the body of the document source.
\begin{document}

%%
%% The "title" command has an optional parameter,
%% allowing the author to define a "short title" to be used in page headers.
\title{The Name of the Title is Hope}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

The Cyrillic letter И can mean the variable \(\mitcyrI\), the constant \(\mupcyrI\), the vector \(\mbfitcyrI\) or the constant vector \(\mbfupcyrI\).  Other forms such as \textsf{И} for tensors could be defined similarly as \(\msfupcyrI\).

\end{document}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `sample-manuscript.tex'.
```

[image: Libertinus font sample]

An alternative would be to `\DeclareMathSymbol`, although this would require you to use up one of the limited number of math alphabets you are allowed to define in legacy TeX.

#### Edit

You mentioned in a comment compiling this in XeLaTeX.  The template does not seem to have been set up to support that, but this quick and dirty hack *appears* to work.  Check with the journal.

```
\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures[LinLibertine]{NFSSFamily=LinuxLibertineT-TLF}
\documentclass[manuscript,screuen,review]{acmart}
\usepackage[nomath]{libertinus}

\newcommand\mitcyrI{\mathord{\text{\rmfamily\mdseries\itshape И}}}
\newcommand\mupcyrI{\mathord{\text{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape И}}}
\newcommand\mbfitcyrI{\mathord{\text{\rmfamily\bfseries\itshape И}}}
\newcommand\mbfupcyrI{\mathord{\text{\rmfamily\bfseries\upshape И}}}
\newcommand\msfupcyrI{\mathord{\text{\sffamily\mdseries\upshape И}}}

%%
%% \BibTeX command to typeset BibTeX logo in the docs
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}

%% Rights management information.  This information is sent to you
%% when you complete the rights form.  These commands have SAMPLE
%% values in them; it is your responsibility as an author to replace
%% the commands and values with those provided to you when you
%% complete the rights form.
\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
\copyrightyear{2018}
\acmYear{2018}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}

%%
%% end of the preamble, start of the body of the document source.
\begin{document}

%%
%% The "title" command has an optional parameter,
%% allowing the author to define a "short title" to be used in page headers.
\title{The Name of the Title is Hope}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

The Cyrillic letter И can mean the variable \(\mitcyrI\), the constant \(\mupcyrI\), the vector \(\mbfitcyrI\) or the constant vector \(\mbfupcyrI\).  Other forms such as \textsf{И} for tensors could be defined similarly as \(\msfupcyrI\).

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are clearly a font-magician. Works like a charm for pdflatex. For `xelatex` I get 7 Warnings in the style of "Font shape `T2A/lmr/m/n' undefined using T2A/cmr/m/n instead", but I think they can be savely ignored.

Comment: @boraas Compiling in XeLaTeX breaks the template. You *might* get it to work by loading the `libertine` package, but you’d really want to contact the journal and ask them what alterations to the template they accept.

Comment: @boraas I added a quick hack to get the template to compile in XeLaTeX with OpenType fonts. I have no idea if it breaks anything else in your document, or whether the journal would accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried multiple ways and concluded that [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557546/211575) is the most flexible way to insert Cyrillic letters in LaTeX math. [This document](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/required/cyrillic/cyoutenc.pdf) contains all the codes for Cyrillic letters in T2A.

Following the answer cited above, I have added the following letters that could be useful in mathematical notations (the second numeric codes are for the lower case letters, which I did not yet import):

> Blockquote

```latex
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrillic}{T2A}{cmr}{m}{n}%{it}
\SetSymbolFont{cyrillic}{bold}{T2A}{cmr}{bx}{n}%{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mBe}{\mathord}{cyrillic}{193}%Б б 225
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mDe}{\mathord}{cyrillic}{196}%Д д 228
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mZhe}{\mathord}{cyrillic}{198}%Ж ж 230
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mI}{\mathord}{cyrillic}{200}%И и
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mEl}{\mathord}{cyrillic}{203}%Л л 235
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mTse}{\mathord}{cyrillic}{214}%Ц ц 246 or 84 116 ?
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mChe}{\mathord}{cyrillic}{215}%Ч ч 247
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mSha}{\mathord}{cyrillic}{216}%Ш ш 248
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mE}{\mathord}{cyrillic}{221}%Э э 253
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mYu}{\mathord}{cyrillic}{222}%Ю ю 254
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mYa}{\mathord}{cyrillic}{223}%Я я 255
```

To use them in math blocks you can simply insert the codes, e.g.:

```latex
$\mathbf{\mZhe}$
```