# Are there math-mode commands to enter cyrillic characters?

Tags: math-mode, cyrillic

Just typing them directly does not work.

Just like `\alpha` is different from `α`, `ю` produces a non-italic letters that also don't follow correct spacing:
`Ю + 1` produces
[image: Ю + 1 but the plus is too far to the right]

Comment: Does this mean you want them in *italic*?  If you want them (in roman) with the correct spacing in math mode, `$\textrm{Ю} +\textrm{ю} + 1$` will do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a new math symbol font.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrillic}{T2A}{cmr}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{cyrillic}{bold}{T2A}{cmr}{bx}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\mYu}{\mathord}{cyrillic}{222}

\begin{document}

$\mYu+1$

{\boldmath$\mYu+1$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Look in your system for the file `t2aenc.def` in order to find the numeric code. The uppercase Ю is called `\CYRYU`.

With `cmap`, the character is copied as itself from the PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any text-mode symbol and formatting commands in math mode with `\textnormal` from `amsmath`.  Here’s [an answer I gave](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542007/cyrillic-letters-acm-template) to a similar question a few months ago.  In this case, you’d want `\textit{ю}` if you want it to appear bold in a bold header, or `\textnormal{\itshape ю}` to have it always appear as medium italic.

The `fontspec` package gives you another option.  It sets `\mathrm`, `\mathit`, etc. to use the main text font, or another you provide.  If you set it to a font that supports Cyrillic (such as `\setmathrm{CMU Serif}[Ligatures={Common,TeX}]`), you can use `\mathrm{ю}`, `\mathit{ю}`, and so on.