# A letter looks like number 3. What is it?

Tags: math-mode

I came across this symbol (the one looks like 3) when I read a book this afternoon. I never saw such a symbol before. Is it a Greek letter? What is its LaTeX code?

[image]

Comment: Looks like the cyrillic `zemlja` (the equivalent of the `Z` for the Latin alphabet).

Comment: Did you try [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org) ?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes, I did. Detexify doesn't give the right one.

Comment: Context from the rest of the book?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR No. The symbol is a representation of a distribution.

Comment: Maybe this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ze_(Cyrillic)

Comment: @HenriMenke I guess so. But do you know the code for it? I tried some possible solutions, but they didn't work.

Comment: @Bernard I think so. It looks like the one I want. Do you know the code for it?

Comment: @jwyao See [Cyrillic in (La)TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/816/cyrillic-in-latex).

Comment: looks like a fraktur Z to me -- `\frak{Z}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you! There is a very subtle difference between them. I am using it for now. Your code is the simplest one that works in my LaTeX file :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is `\mathfrak{Z}` from the STIX font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}

$\sqrt{n} ( \mathscr{K}_n - \mathscr{K} ) \xrightarrow{d} \mathfrak{Z}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

this is almost certainly a fraktur Z  --`$\frak{Z}$`.

while the letter does look quite like the cyrillic Ze, in western math there is a very long history of using the fraktur alphabet, but the only "common" cyrillic letter i know of that has made its way into western math is the Sha (first letter of the name shafarevich, and also used for the shuffle product).

Comment: `\frak_Z+` should be `\frak{Z}`, I presume.

Comment: Also, why is there so little space between `)` and `\xrightarrow` in my answer?

Comment: @HenriMenke -- thanks for noticing typo -- fixed.  (could have sworn i checked that, but machines here have been behaving unpredictably for the past week.)  regarding bad spacing in your answer re stix font, there are still a lot of niceties that have to be sorted out there.  i'll put that on our list.

Comment: @HenriMenke -- on testing your example here, the bad positioning of the arrow is confirmed, but only with stix 1; stix 2 isn't yet fully available, but i will test this when it is.  (so i have a different question -- how did whoever created the example shown in the original question get it right?)

Comment: If one examines over a wide range of Fraktur fonts, **many** of them share this characteristic shape, including the fork of the central stroke, and the curly tail.  Good sleuthing.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- no need to sleuth, actually.  i learned to read fraktur in my childhood.  didn't learn to read cyrillic until i was in college.  so for me, this was a no-brainer.

Comment: At my age, just to recall something I heard last week, I often have to sleuth my brain.  Sometimes, a cup of hot, steaming *covfefe* will help