# What are the ways to use cyrillic symbols in Fancy CV template?

Tags: cyrillic, russian

I want to write a part of the text in Russian:

```
\section{publications}
\small{Сборник тезисов докладов VI научной молодежной школы-конференции «Химия, физика, биология: пути интеграции», 2018,82-83.}
```

I already tried to use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
```

but it doesn't work. What is the problem and the solution?

Comment: The simplest way is probably to use a Unicode-engine such as LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX. (If you switch to LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28642/35864). For short stretches of text you can stick to pdfLaTeX. A great overview over all possible solutions is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/816/35864

Comment: What's the “fancy CV” template? Any pointer?

Comment: https://ru.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/fancy-cv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template you've shown uses a sans serif font without Cyrillic characters (TeXGyre Heros). Therefore you won't be able to put sentences in Russian as is. But you can change the fonts. I've tried to add the following lines to the preamble of `cv.tex`:

```
\newfontfamily\bodyfont{Fira Sans}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{Fira Sans Light}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Fira Sans Bold}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont
[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]
{Fira Sans}

\setmathfont{Fira Sans}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
```

They switch the document font to `Fira Sans` (it's a nice free font family with wide range of weights and with Cyrillic support). After that putting

```
\section{publications}

\otherlanguage{russian}
\small{Сборник тезисов докладов VI научной молодежной школы-конференции
«Химия, физика, биология: пути интеграции», 2018, 82--83.}
```

to the end of the template prints this bibliographic entry just fine.

If your CV is in Russian then you'd want to use

```
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
```

and omit the `\otherlanguage{russian}` altogether.

Comment: `Mapping=tex-text` is already default, so it's not necessary to set it. I don't think it's good advice to recommend `\setmathfont{Fira Sans}`, because Fira Sans is not a math font.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I just took a few lines from the `friggeri-cv.cls` and replaced all the fonts without Cyrillic letters to `Fira Sans`. I could do better :-)