# Spanish and Russian in one thesis

Tags: math-mode, babel, labels, spanish

I'm working on my math thesis and need some cyrilic symbols, so I added `\usepackage[spanish,russian]{babel}` but the rest of the text is in spanish. Now, every "proof, image, bibliography..." is in Russian! How can I forced the these to be in spanish?

Comment: Will there be longer parts of text in russian or do you really just need a few cyrillic symbols here and there?

Comment: [Cyrillic in (La)TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/816/134144) might be relevant if you have longer parts of russian text.

Answer (score 1):

Try `\usepackage[russian,spanish]{babel}` instead. The last language is always the main one.